# How do you keep track of multiple properties of a string without traversing it multiple times?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, traversal

I recently did a practice problem for validating a string.

> Use the `Maybe` type to write a function that counts the number of vowels
>   in a string and the number of consonants. If the number of vowels exceeds
>   the number of consonants, the function returns Nothing.

I ended up two functions for each counting vowels and counting consonants:

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel c = c `elem` "aeiou"

countVowels :: String -> Integer
countVowels []     = 0
countVowels (x:xs) =
  if isVowel x
  then countVowels xs + 1
  else countVowels xs

countConsonants :: String -> Integer
countConsonants []     = 0
countConsonants (x:xs) =
  if not $ isVowel x
  then countConsonants xs + 1
  else countConsonants xs
```

And then just comparing the values of the two to get my answer.

```
makeWord :: String -> Maybe String
makeWord [] = Nothing
makeWord s  =
  if countVowels s < countConsonants s
  then Nothing
  else Just s
```

My problem with this is that it traverses the string twice, once to get the number of vowels and another time to get the number of consonants.

I thought perhaps I could fix this by subtracting the number of vowels from the length of the string to begin with, but that also takes two traversals.

So I tried making a function that tracks both vowels and consonants at once, storing the results in a tuple, but since I didn't know adding tuples is actually pretty hard, the result was even more complex.

```
countVowelsAndConsonants :: String -> [(Integer, Integer)]
countVowelsAndConsonants []     = []
countVowelsAndConsonants (x:xs) =
  if isVowel x
    then (1, 0) : countVowelsAndConsonants xs
    else (0, 1) : countVowelsAndConsonants xs

makeWord :: String -> Maybe String
makeWord [] = Nothing
makeWord s  =
  if countVowels s < countConsonants s
    then Nothing
    else Just s
  where counts = let unzipped = unzip (countVowelsAndConsonants s)
                 in (sum $ fst unzipped, sum $ snd unzipped)
```

and, to be honest, I think this is even worse than what I started off with.

Also, what if I also had to keep track of uppercase and lowercase letters? Then I don't think the tuple approach would scale.

In an imperative language, for example javascript, which I'm more used to, it would be as simple as this to traverse it just once.

```
const word        = "somestring"
let numVowels     = 0
let numConsonants = 0

for (var s of word) isVowel(s) ? numVowels++ : numConsonants++
```

I'm sure Haskell has a way that's just as simple, but unfortunately I'm unfamiliar.

What's the idiomatic way of keeping tabs of multiple properties of a `String` without having to keep traversing it multiple times?

Comment: You could add to a tuple with functions like `incVowel (v, c) = (v + 1)` and `incConsonant (v, c) = (v, c + 1)`. Obviously these functions are very specialised, but hopefully you get the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `foldr` with a state is somewhat simple:

```
countVCs :: String -> (Int, Int)
countVCs str = foldr k (0, 0) str
   where
     k x (v, c) = if isVowel x then (v + 1, c ) else (v , c + 1 )
```

An alternative way would be `Data.List.partition` followed by `length` on both elements of the pair:

```
countVCs :: String -> (Int, Int)
countVCs str = both length (partition isVowel str)
  where 
    both f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

Yet another way is to use `foldMap` with `(Sum Int, Sum Int)`:

```
countVCs :: String -> (Int, Int)
countVCs str = both getSum (foldMap k str)
  where
    k x          = if isVowel x then (Sum 1, Sum 0) else (Sum 0, Sum 1)
    both f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
```

Answer (score 14):

I'd start by defining the traditional "indicator function"

```
indicate :: Num a => Bool -> a
indicate b = if b then 1 else 0
```

so that

```
indicate . isVowel :: Char -> Integer
```

Next, I'd get hold of two key pieces of kit from `Control.Arrow`

```
(&&&) :: (x -> y) -> (x -> z) -> x -> (y, z)
(***) :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (a, c) -> (b, d)
```

so (remembering that some characters are neither vowels nor consonants)

```
(indicate . isVowel) &&& (indicate . isConsonant)
  :: Char -> (Integer, Integer)
```

And then I'd grab hold of `Sum` from `Data.Monoid`.

```
(Sum . indicate . isVowel) &&& (Sum . indicate . isConsonant)
  :: Char -> (Sum Integer, Sum Integer)
getSum *** getSum :: (Sum Integer, Sum Integer) -> (Integer, Integer)
```

Now I deploy `foldMap`, because we're doing some sort of monoidal "crush".

```
(getSum *** getSum) .
foldMap ((Sum . indicate . isVowel) &&& (Sum . indicate . isConsonant))
  :: String -> (Integer, Integer)
```

Then I remember that I wrote some code which got turned into `Control.Newtype` and I discover the following is missing but should be there.

```
instance (Newtype n o, Newtype n' o') => Newtype (n, n') (o, o') where
  pack = pack *** pack
  unpack = unpack *** unpack
```

And now I need only write

```
ala' (Sum *** Sum) foldMap ((indicate . isVowel) &&& (indicate . isConsonant))
  :: String -> (Integer, Integer)
```

The key gadget is

```
ala' :: (Newtype n o, Newtype n' o') =>
 (o -> n) -> ((a -> n) -> b -> n') -> (a -> o) -> b -> o'
-- ^-packer    ^-higher-order operator  ^-action-on-elements
```

where the packer's job is to select the newtype with the correct behavioral instance and also determine the unpacker. It's exactly designed to support working locally at a more specific type that signals the intended structure.

Comment: I'm sure this is an extremely good answer, but for a beginner like me, it was a bit over my head. I really appreciate the answer though, and I'll definitely be looking back on it later when I'm more experienced.

Comment: I'm sorry it's a bit much. There's certainly a whole bunch of concepts and techniques coming together to produce that solution, and if most or all of them are new, it'll take quite some digestion. But there is one theme: we use types not only to describe valid data layouts, but also to identify computational structure that we can exploit (how to traverse, how to combine the things we compute from each element). Becoming aware of useful structure (often captured by type classes) is a really useful part of learning Haskell, because it's how you get the compiler to write code for you.

Comment: No need to apologize. I'll definitely keep that in mind, and it's interesting thinking of it as getting "the compiler to write code for you."

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way is to use a 'beautiful folding' library like [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.1.6/docs/Control-Foldl.html). Then this problem basically reduces to writing a single expression. I will divide it up:

```
import qualified Control.Foldl as L
import Control.Lens

isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel c = c `elem` "aeiou"

countVowels, countConsonants :: L.Fold Char Int
countVowels = L.handles (filtered isVowel) L.length
countConsonants  = L.handles (filtered (not.isVowel)) L.length

lessVowels :: L.Fold Char Bool
lessVowels  = (<) <$> countVowels <*> countConsonants 

makeWord :: String -> Maybe String
makeWord s =  if L.fold lessVowels s then Nothing else Just s
```

so then I have, say

```
 >>> makeWord "aaa"
 Just "aaa"
 >>> makeWord "ttt"
 Nothing
```

With `foldl` you can run indefinitely many folds on the same material simultaneously. The sequence of elements can be a pure list, vector or array, or an effectful stream like a pipe or conduit. The composition of folds is indifferent to what, in the end, you fold it over.

I used `handles` above, which is a little sophisticated, maybe, since it uses lenses, but this allows the different folds to take account of different sorts of elements. So here, one fold is only 'looking' at vowels, the other at consonants. It would be simple to write these folds by hand, and dispense with the `filtered isVowel` lens.

Comment: I think this is the best practical answer.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the most idiomatic way in functional programming is to not worry about the extra traversal, and go for the improved readability and composability offered by the more simple solution.  Two traversals are still `O(n)`.  Unless your string is huge or read from a non-reversible source like a network stream, the performance difference of the two traversals is negligible.

Also, you don't need to use recursion.  `countVowels` and `countConsonants` can be implemented as:

```hs
countVowels = length . filter isVowel
countConsonants = length . filter (not . isVowel)
```

Comment: I figured as much, but it was the fact that I didn't even know how to achieve single traversal even if I wanted to that bothered me.